# How to install a .qtz screensaver in Lion?

Tags: macos, screensaver

What are the instructions to install a .qtz screensaver in Lion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move it into `~/Library/Screen Savers` if you are the only one who wants to use it, or into `/Library/screen Savers` if you want all users on the machine to have access to it (note `~/Library` is hidden by default in Lion: you can access it by holding Option when clicking the “Go To” menu in Finder).